# How to do maintenance on data for a long running web application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Looking for suggestions....

We have an ASP.NET web application running under windows environment with data storage on SQL Server. Application has been in production environment for over 3 years. Mostly client needs access to last 6 months of data only so remaining data mostly not needed and he feels when we do so application would be more faster than previous as data querying would be reduced. So we are looking for a best industry practice that we can manage old data.

Old data should be maintained as history of data and should not be deleted permanently. Maybe when needed we should be able to look.

We hope/believe that industry definitely will came across such a situation and there is some definitely best standards to follow meeting our requirements.

Thanks,

Selva

Comment: You don’t need to remove old data - indexed data retrieval is O( log n ) - (e.g. searching over 1,000,000 records takes only twice as long as searching over 1,000 records). If you have poor perf at scale then the issue is likely missing indexes or fragmentation or just a poor database design - or your program is reading everything into memory instead of executing queries on the DBMS - or you have underprovisioned hardware.

Comment: @Dai As per your suggestion we no need to move records anywhere and focus on finding and improving indexing, server resources and scaling.